# Changing data dynamically on flip card Fragments using Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, flipview

I am trying to use flip animations in Android for practising vocabulary. I have made a container for my Fragments:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:onClick="flipCard"
 />
```

and two Fragments: `fragment_card_flip.xml` and `fragment_card_back.xml`. One is for showing the word and the other, the meaning on the back of the card.

I am getting a word from database randomly and want to change the text in both Fragments i.e., put the word on the front Fragment and the meaning on the back Fragment. In the `onClick()` in the Fragment I am calling a `flipcard()` function:

```
public void flipCard(View view) {
    if (mShowingBack) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        mShowingBack=false;
    f = (Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    if(f!=null)
        ((TextView) f.getView().findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(w);
        return;
    }

    // Flip to the back.

    mShowingBack = true;

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(
                    R.animator.card_flip_right_in,
                    R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                    R.animator.card_flip_left_in,
                    R.animator.card_flip_left_out)

            .replace(R.id.container, new CardBackFragment())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

This is my attempt to change the word only, not the definition. But I can't change the text data of the Fragment dynamically. Please help me to update both my Fragments dynamically with a new word/meaning from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first step is to change your Fragments so that they take the word they will display as an argument:

```
public class CardFlip extends Fragment {

    public static String ARGUMENT_WORD = "ARGUMENT_WORD"

    public static CardFlip instantiate(String text) {
        CardFlip cardFlip = new CardFlip();
        Bundle argsBundle = new Bundle();
        argsBundle.putString(ARGUMENT_WORD, text);
        cardFlip.setArguments(argsBundle);
        return cardFlip;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String text = getArguments().getString(ARGUMENT_WORD);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(text);
    }
}
```

Do this for both Fragments. Now you can make fragments dynamically with the words you want.

Now all you need to do is refactor your `flipcard()` method so that it uses the static `instantiate` method rather than the `new CardFlip()` constructor. Since you always want your Fragments to be up-to-date with the latest words, don't use `popBackStack()` use `FragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace()`. Something like this:

```
public void flipCard(View view) {
    Fragment frag;
    if (mShowingBack) {
        frag = CardFlip.instantiate(currentWord);
    }
    else {
        frag = CardBack.instantiate(currentWord);
    }
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag)
           .commit();
}
```

Then all you need is some logic for when to change the word randomly.

These are all concepts from the official [developer's guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) so you study this very carefully: consider reading the guide there multiple times and taking notes.

Comment: tried this but got this error 'java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.Bundle.putString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference'

Comment: @Igniter I updated my answer to fix the mistake. But please read the tutorial too!

Comment: Thank you so much @David Rawson . Your answer helped me :) but' super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);' should also be added in onActivityCreated method.